# Lazy load module on same path based on guard

Tags: angular, lazy-loading, angular-module, angular-guards

I want to load a specific Angular Module based on a user role on the same ("") path (home). Let's say, I have two modules named AdminModule and OperatorModule. If the role is ADMIN then I want to load the AdminModule otherwise the OperatorModule. I want to archive this with an Angular Guard.

Now in `app.routing.ts` I added the following code:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

import { AuthGuard } from './core/guards/auth.guard';

import { AdminModule } from './modules/admin';
import { OperatorModule } from './modules/operator';

const routes: Routes = [
   {
      path: '',
      loadChildren: () => AdminModule,
      canLoad: [ AuthGuard ],
      data: { role: 'ADMIN' }
   },

   {
      path: '',
      loadChildren: () => OperatorModule,
      canLoad: [ AuthGuard ],
      data: { role: 'OPERATOR' }
   },
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

I have implemented an AngularGuard with the following code, which has to show the OperatorModule:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { CanLoad, Route, Router } from '@angular/router';

@Injectable({
   providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthGuard implements CanLoad {
   constructor(private router: Router) {}

   canLoad(route: Route): Promise<boolean> | boolean {
      if (route.data.role === 'OPERATOR') {
         return true;
      }

      return false;
   }
}
```

Somehow it stops looking after the first route fails, am I doing something wrong?

StackBlitz example by djerid: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vd4oyu?file=app%2Fapp-routing.module.ts

===

Matcher does not work either:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

import { AuthGuard } from './core/guards/auth.guard';

import { AdminModule } from './modules/admin';
import { OperatorModule } from './modules/operator';

const routes: Routes = [
   {
      loadChildren: () => AdminModule,
      matcher: AdminMatcher,
      data: { role: 'NO' }
   },

   {
      loadChildren: () => OperatorModule,
      matcher: OperatorMatcher,
      data: { role: 'OPERATOR' }
   },
];

@NgModule({
   imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
   exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule {
   constructor() {

   }
}


import { UrlSegment, UrlSegmentGroup, Route } from '@angular/router';
export function AdminMatcher(segments: UrlSegment[], group: UrlSegmentGroup, route: Route) {
   const isPathMatch = segments[0].path === route.path;

   if (isPathMatch && route.data.role === 'ADMIN') {
      return { consumed: [segments[0]] };
   } else {
      return null;
   }
}

export function OperatorMatcher(segments: UrlSegment[], group: UrlSegmentGroup, route: Route) {
   const isPathMatch = segments[0].path === route.path;

   if (isPathMatch && route.data.role === 'OPERATOR') {
      return { consumed: [segments[0]] };
   } else {
      return null;
   }
}
```

Comment: Can you reproduce the issue on [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com)?

Comment: Here a similar issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49405281/angular-5-conditional-module-lazy-loading

Comment: @MichaelDesigaud I see, but the solution they have is to have the modules on different paths. I think it is not possible, right? :(

Comment: @TilakDewangan added a Stackblitz with the exact same issue by djerid :)

Comment: @YanickvanBarneveld Yes if you have identical paths the last one will override the others

Comment: @MichaelDesigaud And you think there is no solution for this? I think it is a issue more people will have right? :P

Comment: @YanickvanBarneveld you have to define one path and perform redirection in you Guard based on the user role

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191737/discussion-between-yanick-van-barneveld-and-michael-desigaud).

Answer (score 0):

the best is to use [UrlMatchers](https://angular.io/api/router/UrlMatcher) instead of canLoad for that, to match each one base on your conditions, when one of the 2 path is matched the other one will be ignored automatically

```
 const routes: Routes = [{
  path: '',
  matcher: adminMatcher,
  oadChildren: () => AdminModule,
  data: { role: 'ADMIN' }
 },
 {
  path: '',
  matcher: operatormatcher,
  loadChildren: () => OperatorModule,
  data: { role: 'OPERATOR' }

 }]
```

check this [example](https://medium.com/@lenseg1/loading-different-angular-modules-or-components-on-routes-with-same-path-2bb9ba4b6566)

Comment: I tried however does not seems to work, see edited answer. Also with removing isPathMatch is does not work... :(

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question, but I am leaving an answer here in case someone stumbles upon this question. I solved this problem by using the root module's `injector` in my lazy-loaded route.

You can check out the working solution on [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-fxiae7?file=src/main.ts).

### Solution

#### Step 1

Create a new file that exports an `ReplaySubject<Injector>`.

```js
import { Injector } from '@angular/core';
import { ReplaySubject } from 'rxjs';

// Feel free to optimize this implementation if you want to
// expose `Observable<Injector>` instead of the subject itself.
export const appInjector = new ReplaySubject<Injector>();
```

#### Step 2

In `main.ts`, get a handle to the root module's `Injector` and publish it to the `appInjector` subject you created above:

```js
platformBrowserDynamic()
  .bootstrapModule(AppModule)
  .then((m) => appInjector.next(m.injector)) // publish root module's injector
  .catch((err) => console.error(err));
```

#### Step 3

This is the step where we modify the route that needs to asynchronously lazy-load different modules based on some asynchronous condition.

```js
const routes: Routes = [
  // other routes
  // ...
  // ...
  // conditional route
  {
    path: "dashboard",
    component: LayoutComponent,
    canActivate: [DashboardAuthGuard], // block this route if user is not logged-in
    loadChildren: () =>
    
      // Use the appInjector subject
      appInjector.pipe(
        
        // ...to get a handle to your AuthService
        map((injector) => injector.get(AuthService)),
        
        // ...then switch to a new observable
        switchMap((authService) => {
          
          // ...that uses authService to retrieve the logged-in user
          return authService.user$.pipe(
            
            // ...then switches again, this time to actually lazy-load a feature module
            switchMap((user) => {
              
              // ...but first let's check the user's role
              switch (user.role) {
                
                // ...and load Admin Feature Module if user.role is 'admin'
                case "admin":
                  return import(
                    "./modules/admin-dashboard/admin-dashboard.module"
                  ).then((m) => m.AdminDashboardModule);
                
                // ...or load User Feature Module if user.role is 'user'
                case "user":
                  return import(
                    "./modules/user-dashboard/user-dashboard.module"
                  ).then((m) => m.UserDashboardModule);
              }
            })
          );
        })
      ),
  },
];
```