# Unable to router.navigate to lazy loaded child modules

Tags: angular, angular-routing, angular-router-guards

I'm new to angular. I am starting with the latest version, 8.

I am trying to write an app. The initial state of the route is path:'' and I would like to determine the next route based on some condition in the base path here. If the condition is true, I need to redirect the user to /home and if it fails, I need to redirect to /welcome. Both home and welcome are lazily loaded.

I have a guard service where the routing decision is made (which path to take).

**app-routing.ts**

```
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router'; 
import { HomeGuardService } from './services/route-guard/home-guard.service';


const routes: Routes = 
[ 
    { 
        path: '', pathMatch: 'full', 
        canActivate: [HomeGuardService], 
        children: 
        [ 
            { path: 'welcome', loadChildren: () => import('./welcome/welcome.module').then(mod => mod.WelcomeModule), }, 
            { path: 'home', loadChildren: () => import('./home/home.module').then(mod => mod.HomeModule) } 
        ] 
    } 
]; 

@NgModule({ imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)], exports: [RouterModule] }) 
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

**home-guard.service.ts**

```
import { ActivatedRouteSnapshot, RouterStateSnapshot } from '@angular/router/src/router_state'; 
import { LocalStorageService } from '../storage/local-storage.service'; 

@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' }) 
export class HomeGuardService implements CanActivate { 

    constructor( private router: Router) { } 

    canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot) { return this.checkCountrySelection(state); } 


    private checkCountrySelection(state: RouterStateSnapshot): boolean { 
        if (<my_condition>) { 
            this.router.navigate(['home']); 
            return true; 
        } 
        this.router.navigateByUrl('welcome'); 
        return false; 
    } 
}
```

Now, with this setup, angular complains that it cannot match any routes for URL Segment: 'welcome'

(Initially, I have made the condition to fail in home-guard service to it would load the welcome module)

Comment: Welcome and Home should not be children of default path

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't define children to the default path, you can change your routes array to :

```
const routes: Routes = 
[ 
  { 
    path: 'welcome',
    canActivate: [HomeGuardService],
    loadChildren: () => import('./welcome/welcome.module').then(mod => mod.WelcomeModule)
  },
  { 
    path: 'home',
    canActivate: [HomeGuardService],
    loadChildren: () => import('./home/home.module').then(mod => mod.HomeModule)
  }
  ...
```

Comment: I actually do not want to load any component or module for the default path. I want it to load either home or welcome.

If i would not make them children, the default path would require me to add a component or module . It says - One of the following must be provided: component, redirectTo, children or loadChildren

Comment: I have modified the route to load home to root path and redirect to welcome when  condition fails(in the guard)

Answer (score 2):

Your routes are children of a guarded group.

In case it doesn't speak to you : **if you can't access the group because of the guard, you won't be able to access the children because of the guard**.

The guard is ran **for every route depth**, and if one fails and redirects, the following routes won't be reached.

You have to take your routes out of the guarded route to make it work.

Comment: Thanks ! I actually can understand this.
Infact, i followed couple of things like these -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49405281/angular-5-conditional-module-lazy-loading